# Shell Scipt sub string

Tags: shell, substring

Please help me to get script for below case.

I Have my content of file like below,

**AllIdPropert.txt (ID|PropertyBit|)**

```
1|0000000000000000000000000|
2|0000100000000000000000000|
3|0000100000000000000000000|
4|0000100000000000000000000|
5|0000000000000000000000000| 
6|0000000000000000000000000|
```

I need to extract all the Id's into different file where PropertyBit[5] == 1(Where 5th bit is 1) in the format as below.

5bitenable.txt

```
2|
3| 
4|
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this awk one-liner should do the job:

```
awk -F'|' 'substr($2,5,1)==1 {print $1FS}' file
```

test with your example input:

```
kent$  awk -F'|' 'substr($2,5,1)==1 {print $1FS}' f
2|
3|
4|
```

Comment: Thank u Kent, it exactly serving what i need.

Comment: @Suman no problem. but it would be good for you to understand how it worked. It is really fundamental awk usage. So that in future if you have similar requirement, you could handle them on your own.